# How do I get rid of a text that is being automatically added to text fields? Bug?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, buddypress

First post here because I'm desperate trying to find an answer to this.
I'm working on a Wordpress page using Buddy press and BuddyPress Xprofile Custom Field Types (among other plugins). A couple of days ago a text has been added to all my text fields, out of the blue, I haven't changed anything.
I tried deactivating plugins, checking for updates, but nothing is helping.

I've doing some customization on the member's 'index' and 'members-loop' php files and I use Themify as my main theme.

Below you can find the text that it's being automatically added to my text fields.

I appreciate any help or guidance.
Thanks!!

```
TRANSLATE with x

English

Arabic
Hebrew
Polish

Bulgarian
Hindi
Portuguese

Catalan
Hmong Daw
Romanian

Chinese Simplified
Hungarian
Russian

Chinese Traditional
Indonesian
Slovak

Czech
Italian
Slovenian

Danish
Japanese
Spanish

Dutch
Klingon
Swedish

English
Korean
Thai

Estonian
Latvian
Turkish

Finnish
Lithuanian
Ukrainian

French
Malay
Urdu

German
Maltese
Vietnamese

Greek
Norwegian
Welsh

Haitian Creole
Persian

var LanguageMenu; var LanguageMenu_keys=["ar","bg","ca","zh-CHS","zh-CHT","cs","da","nl","en","et","fi","fr","de","el","ht","he","hi","mww","hu","id","it","ja","tlh","ko","lv","lt","ms","mt","no","fa","pl","pt","ro","ru","sk","sl","es","sv","th","tr","uk","ur","vi","cy"]; var LanguageMenu_values=["Arabic","Bulgarian","Catalan","Chinese Simplified","Chinese Traditional","Czech","Danish","Dutch","English","Estonian","Finnish","French","German","Greek","Haitian Creole","Hebrew","Hindi","Hmong Daw","Hungarian","Indonesian","Italian","Japanese","Klingon","Korean","Latvian","Lithuanian","Malay","Maltese","Norwegian","Persian","Polish","Portuguese","Romanian","Russian","Slovak","Slovenian","Spanish","Swedish","Thai","Turkish","Ukrainian","Urdu","Vietnamese","Welsh"]; var LanguageMenu_callback=function(){ }; var LanguageMenu_popupid='__LanguageMenu_popup';

TRANSLATE with

COPY THE URL BELOW
<!--a id="TwitterLink" title="Share on Twitter"> </a--> 
Back

EMBED THE SNIPPET BELOW IN YOUR SITE

Enable collaborative features and customize widget: Bing Webmaster Portal
Back

var intervalId = setInterval(function () { if (MtPopUpList) { LanguageMenu = new MtPopUpList(); var langMenu = document.getElementById(LanguageMenu_popupid); var origLangDiv = document.createElement("div"); origLangDiv.id = "OriginalLanguageDiv"; origLangDiv.innerHTML = "ORIGINAL: "; langMenu.appendChild(origLangDiv); LanguageMenu.Init('LanguageMenu', LanguageMenu_keys, LanguageMenu_values, LanguageMenu_callback, LanguageMenu_popupid); window["LanguageMenu"] = LanguageMenu; clearInterval(intervalId); } }, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution, it was caused by a translation plugin that I had installed on Safari (Mate Translate), deactivating it fixes the problem.